# While loops and duplicate code in python

Tags: python, while-loop, code-duplication

I have a tiny section in my code where I check for active threads that are non-daemon and non-main. These threads needs to be closed eventually, but the part where I check for them is duplicated as follows:

```
threads = [th for th in threading.enumerate() 
           if th is not threading.main_thread() or not th.isDaemon()]
while threads:
    threads = [th for th in threading.enumerate() 
               if th is not threading.main_thread() or not th.isDaemon()]
    time.sleep(5)
exit()
```

I can  also try creating a variable named `count` and check the same with the function `threading.active_count()`. I always try to avoid making a `count` variable whenever I can. It is indeed better than code duplication. Are there any other, more elegant, ways to do this?

Comment: Why not just start with `threads = 1`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 That's exactly what I meant by saying `count`. It is a good idea, but I was looking for an alternative that would avoid creating a new variable.

Comment: Maybe make a function and stick the list comprehension inside? Then instead of duplicating the list comprehension, just call your function twice?

Comment: Try subclass the thread class and make a global static count variable in the module code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried something and it worked. This could either be a dumb solution or a super-dumb question. Anyway, this is what I did:

```
while [th for th in threading.enumerate() 
       if th is not threading.main_thread() and not th.isDaemon()]:
    sleep(5)
exit()
```

And this works. I didn't knew I could do that. D'oh!

Comment: Note that you don't really need to construct the whole list every time. You just need to know whether the list *would* contain at least one element. You can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) for that: `while any(th is not threading.main_thread() or not th.isDaemon() for th in threading.enumerate()): sleep(5)`. That uses a generator, so the test is only performed as much as necessary for `any` to find a matching thread.

Comment: @RobKennedy Excellent

Comment: @RobKennedy I just noticed a tiny bug in there. The `or` should be `and` inside the `any` function. This is because `main-thread` itself is not a daemon thread, hence `any` will give a false positive.

Comment: Make sure you fix it, then. That bug has been in your code all along. It doesn't really change the question or the answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
threads = [th for th in threading.enumerate() 
           if th is not threading.main_thread() or not th.isDaemon()]
while threads:
    # pseudocode:
    kill threads.pop()
    time.sleep(5)
exit()
```